# Querying ServiceBus Metrics using REST and PowerShell returns null value

Tags: powershell, azureservicebus, servicebus, azure-eventhub, azure-servicebus-queues

I am trying to retrieve metrics like length and size for Azure Service Bus Queue / Event Hubs using REST API and PowerShell

PROBLEM1:
I use the below code to invoke REST API. 
While it does return a response, the Values are always empty.
I tried creating queue and eventhub in both ASM and ARM portal with same results

```html
Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri https://management.core.windows.net/mysubscriberid/services/servicebus/Namespaces/maxsb2/Queues/maxqueue2/Metrics `
-CertificateThumbprint mycertthumbprint `
-Headers @{"x-ms-version" = "2015-08-01";'Content-Type'='application/json'}
```

The output looks like this, with empty values

```html
Name               : size
Unit               : bytes
PrimaryAggregation : Max
Rollups            : {@{TimeGrain=00:05:00; Retention=02:00:00; Values=}, @{TimeGrain=01:00:00; Retention=7.00:00:00; Values=}, @{TimeGrain=1.00:00:00; Retention=60.00:00:00; 
                     Values=}, @{TimeGrain=7.00:00:00; Retention=730.00:00:00; Values=}}
DisplayName        : Size


Name               : length
Unit               : Messages
PrimaryAggregation : Max
Rollups            : {@{TimeGrain=00:05:00; Retention=02:00:00; Values=}, @{TimeGrain=01:00:00; Retention=7.00:00:00; Values=}, @{TimeGrain=1.00:00:00; Retention=60.00:00:00; 
                     Values=}, @{TimeGrain=7.00:00:00; Retention=730.00:00:00; Values=}}
DisplayName        : Length
```

PROBLEM2:
A second problem i am having is when using the filter keyword.

```html
https://management.core.windows.net/mysubscriptionID/services/servicebus/Namespaces/MaxServiceBus/EventHubs/maxevent/Metrics/requests.total/Rollups/PT5M/Values?$filter=Timestamp%20le%20datetime'2017-05-19T21:00:00Z'
```

PowerShell interprets $filter as a variable and causes issues. I have tried using ` to escape, also tried using single/double quotes but these end up throwing a misleading authentication error instead.

if i try to use the below syntax to solve the $filter issue,

```html
$uri = 'https://management.core.windows.net/{}/services/ServiceBus/Namespaces/maxeventhub/eventhubs/maxevent/Metrics/Rollups/P1D/Values/?$' + 'filter=Timestamp%20gt%20datetime' + '2017-04-09T00:00:00.0000000Z' + '&api-version=2015-08-01'

Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $uri `
-Headers @{"Authorization" ="Bearer $($authv.access_token)";"x-ms-version" = "2015-08-01";'Content-Type'='application/json'} `
-CertificateThumbprint {}
```

i get a different error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8cAZ.png)

```html
Invoke-RestMethod : Request to a downlevel service failed.
```

It seems like auth is working fine as i do get a response now, have certificate uploaded to portal, just that the values are null.
Any ideas?

Comment: Metrics endpoint from Problem1 only returns the list of metrics, not values of those metrics. To get the values, you need to query individual metric as in Problem2.

Comment: Actually, that is what i am doing, just pasted it incorrectly, If you look at the output, its Values are null. Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri https://management.core.windows.net/mysubscriberid/services/servicebus/Namespaces/maxsb2/Queues/maxqueue2/Metrics/length